# Cant Get data from explode function

Tags: explode

I tried to echo a row from html data but it shows blank page . Please help.

```
<?php
$url_data    = file_get_contents('http://www.nowgoal.com/analysis/1374177.html');
$rows        = explode("\n",$url_data);
echo $rows[1];?>
```

Comment: explode fungtion used for string only. what dou you want to echo?

Comment: echo a string of html data . example : "<h1 id="Head2_ht2" style="font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Live Scores &amp; Odds  Comparison</h1>" . Thank lqbal.

Comment: In your code example, `$rows[1]` contains HTML tag: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. When you echo this string, your browser will parse it as HTML DOCTYPE, thus the blank page.

Comment: I think it is not possible to retrieve the string from the html type file

Comment: If you want to echo the HTML as a string, try this: `echo htmlentities($rows[1]);`

Comment: @Iqbal `file_get_contents()` returns the content of HTML file (or any file) as a string.

Comment: sorry im new at PHP . i try htmlentities and its echo successful . thank guys for help . nice day ;)

Comment: @Ignatius. You are right man. Thanks for the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$f = fopen ("file.html", "r");
$ln = 0;
while ($line= fgets ($f)) {
    if ($line===FALSE) print ("FALSE\n");
    else $rows[$ln] = htmlspecialchars($line);

    $ln++;
}
print $rows[1];
fclose ($f);
```